# Hours and days of operation in Spanish?

Tags: tiempo

I need to express hours of operation in Spanish. I have made the attempt but am not sure if this is correct, and can't find much online on how this should go in spoken rather than written Spanish. Would appreciate a correction.

> "Nuestras horas de operación son: lunes hasta sábado, a las nueve de la mañana hasta nueve de la noche, domingo a las diez de la mañana hasta siete de la tarde"

In English, what I'm wanting to express in Spanish:

> "Our hours of operation are: Monday through Saturday, 9 AM to 9 PM, Sunday 10 AM to 7 PM".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usualmente se recalca el inicio del horario con la preposición "de" - "from",  y haces la relación o marcas el rango con la preposición "a" - "to", para el ejemplo que das sería: `nuestras horas de operación son: de 9 a. m. a 9 p. m.`

Pero otra forma de decirlo de manera plural sería: `desde las 9 a. m. hasta las 9 p. m.`
nota que en este caso las preposiciones cambian y se agrega el pronombre "las" sin embargo las dos maneras son correctas.

Para el caso de los días es prácticamente igual: `desde el lunes hasta el sábado`, `de lunes a sábado`.

Regularmente se usa la manera corta: `de lunes a sábado de 9 a. m. a 9 p. m., domingo de 10 a. m. a 7 p. m.`

Usualmente se usa "mañana" para sustituir "a. m." y tarde para sustituir "p. m." pero en algunos países las 7 p. m. es noche y no "tarde", por lo que es mejor usar las abreviaturas. "a. m." "p. m."

Comment: De acuerdo a la RAE las abreviaturas son "a. m." y "p. m." utilizando minúsculas y punto después de cada letra y espacio entre las "dos" abreviaturas. http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=YNoTWNJnAD6bhhVBf9  Edité la respuesta para reflejar esta norma de la RAE.

Comment: Gracias lo tendré en cuenta

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con que *a. m.* y *p. m.* sea mejor. Lo normal y cotidiano para mostrar las horas de una tienda es usar el sistema de 24 horas. Nunca en mi vida he escuchado *a. m.* en el español oral.

Comment: Si lo dices por anotación de la respuesta la forma de expresarlo depende mucho de la región, en mi país de origen por ejemplo no es común que se exprese en sistema de 24 horas sea verbal o escrito, p. ej. "Nos vemos a las dieciocho treinta" o "mi horario es de 7:00 a 17:00". Lo usual (estoy seguro que en mas de un país de Latinoamerica) es escribir  "mi horario es de 7 a. m. a 5 p. m." incluso actividades laborales o de otra índole que tienen un horario preestablecido se expresa "mi horario es de 7 a 5". sin embargo aconsejo que es mejor usar p. m. que "tarde" por las razones ya expuestas.

Answer (score 11):

Personally, I've never heard "horas de operación" in Spain. Some other expressions that sound more familiar to me are:

- ***Horario comercial***
- ***Horario de servicio***
- ***Horario de atención***
- ***Horario de funcionamiento***

If you want to keep it with the word "operación", I suggest ***horario* de operación**.

Also, in Spain the 24-hour time notation is more popular (only when writing, of course. Rarely do you hear "Son las diecinueve y veinticinco"). I don't know if that's the case for other Spanish speaking countries.

I would also change some prepositions:

> Lunes **a** sábado, **de** nueve de la mañana **a** nueve de la noche, domingo **de** diez de la mañana **a** siete de la tarde.

or...

> Lunes **a** sábado, **de** 09:00 **a** 21:00, domingo **de** 10:00 **a** 19:00.

Note how I dropped some of the articles. When communicating this kind of things, you want to be succint. People can read it faster, process it easily and remember it better.